# What is the latex equivalent for etc, versus. How do we represent them?

Tags: spacing, macros, symbols, characters

I have gone through some of the questions on SO related to etc and other similar short hand characters. Everywhere is it problem specific. So I would like to know, is there a special command in latex, without defining out own command for using etc.

some thing goes for versus, a vs b ? how do we represent them?

Thanks.

Comment: you type it as `e`,`t`,`c`,`.` ?

Comment: @percusse...In case of some publications, does one dot is good or three dots are good ? I have seen both. So isn't there a universal standard in using it ? or does it user specific?

Comment: I have never seen three dots (ellipsis they are called). You either leave ellipsis or etc. not both of them as far as I know.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi...Thanks for the suggestion, I will make a custom command and will use it whenever required.

Comment: You can use `\textdiscount` (from the `textcomp` package) to denote "versus".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no command for this but `\dots`. In my eyes, dots are too informal for publications. Just use `etc.\` in the middle of a sentence and `etc.` at its end. Or `\&c.\` respectively. Versus should always be `vs.\`. In any case, make sure to use a custom command for this. As you seem to care for such things, you might change your mind later on and then you will be grateful for a custom command.

Comment: `vs.\ ` is sometimes simply `v.\ `, especially in American legal publications. As usual in typography, "always" is a bit strong.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii True. I was referring to the back slash, as it will be in the middle of the sentence in most cases. I guess, there will be many variants for both, vs. and etc.

Comment: Control space (`\␣`) appends glue as if spacefactor were 1000.  Instead of control space I suggest restoring the spacefactor to what it was before placing the dot and delimiting the control sequence by a token whereafter spaces get tokenized: ``\def\vs.{vs.\spacefactor=\the\sfcode`\v}`` and ``\def\etc.{etc.\spacefactor=\the\sfcode`\c}``.  If you don't have the spacefactor restored, the spacefactor of a dot ending a sentence might erroneouly be used in situations where no spaces but closing parentheses follow the abbreviation-dot - e.g., :  Animals (zebras, gnus, etc.) are in the wilderness.